# Creating stepper motor driver using only TTL ICs

Tags: stepper-motor, 555, logic-gates, ttl, stepper-driver

I am trying to drive a 5-wire unipolar stepper motor WITHOUT a microcontroller or driver ic, just using logic gates and JK flip flops (74LS107N's). The motor shaft needs to rotate a certain number of times to displace a set amount of inches in both a cw and ccw direction. The amount of inches will be based on an input sequence of switches / buttons. I am more concerned with driving of the motor than the displacement part right now. I have built an astable 555 with a potentiometer to adjust the clock signal frequency. I wanted to use this to somehow be the input to the "step driver" so that when I reach my displacement destination I can just ground the 555 reset and everything will stop. I have TIP120's and TIP42's to use also.

Any advice or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with both hands tied behind your back?  If your goal is to build a digital logic system, then do that, and don't involve the motor.  If your goal is to drive a motor to accomplish a meaningful tasks, use appropriate parts - either stepper sequencers, or more likely an MCU.  Your question as it stands is both too broad and too impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how my approach would be:

1. Become familiar with the different ways of driving a stepper motor.  The Wikipedia article on stepper motors has a good summary.  The easiest way appears to be the Wave Drive method since only one phase is active at a time.
   [image: Stepper motor drive methods]
2. Write down the basic logic you'd need to drive the motor in one direction.  From the figure, it looks like it would be pretty simple to implement.  (E.g. if A was high, set B and clear A.  If B was high, set C and clear A...).  Now convert that to logic gates and flip-flops.
3. Verify your logic with a software simulator, or build it and capture the output with a logic analyzer or LEDs.  For the LED method I'd slow down the clock speed to a Hz or two, or even use a push-button for the clock signal.
4. Repeat steps 2 for reverse direction.
5. Combine the two directions on paper and see if you can simplify the circuit at all.  Otherwise you may end up with AND gates at the CLEAR pins of each flip-flop, which is fine.
6. Repeat step 3 with the whole circuit.

Step 5 kind of violates the 'make it work, make it right, make it fast' principle ('fast' being replaced by 'simple' in this case) so you can omit that if desired.

Comment: That sounds like it would be easily implemented with a one-hot shift register type system.

Comment: @pjc50 Indeed, but I assumed 'logic gates' meant (N)ANDs, (N/X)ORs, and NOTs.